# List View in C#

Tags: c#

I have a ListView in my C# and I want to select an item based on a number which I give. Is this possible ?

Example: if my List which has add , multiply and divide as elements  in list . so if I give 2 it must select multiply. All these must be done programatically

Comment: is this winforms? webforms? wpf?

Comment: what do you mean List add, multiply and divide ? Do you mean you want to add, multiply or divide the number within the listviewitem with another number ?

Comment: @Andrew: I think he tries to exemplify a list containing the [Add, Multiply, Divide] elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the ListItem value is 2 - I'd simply go with:

```
_listView.SelectedValue = "2";
```

or perhaps more correctly:

```
_listView.SelectedValue = _input.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to select an item by it's index.

If it's for WinForms, you can clear the [SelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx) collection, and add your item index:

```
listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView.SelectedIndices.Add(yourIndex);
```

For WebForms, you have the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex.aspx) property:

```
listView.SelectedIndex = yourIndex;
```

Remember that the indexes are zero-based.